# Importar archivo EXCEL (xlsl) a Tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, archivo, sql-server-2012

Lo que necesito es poder cargar los datos de una hoja Excel a una tabla. Ya probé con bcp. También con Bulk Insert y por último habilité:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;
GO 
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Y probé de hacerlo con: `OPENROWSET`

De ninguna forma logré hacerlo, solo conseguí que se insertara un solo registro con caracteres especiales.

Antes de enviar la consulta, visite muchas páginas y nadie tiene una solución adecuada para esto.

Necesito hacerlo desde un procedimiento para luego automatizarlo, por eso no utilizo el wizard que seguramente podría hacerlo en escasos segundos.

Comment: Consulta, que motor de base de datos estas usando?

Comment: Hey Oscar, bienvenido!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a tu pregunta  para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Comment: ¿Quieres importar directamente el excel?

Comment: Si, Quiero directamente cargar un Excel a una tabla. Asi como con bcp puedo crear un archivo con el resultado de una consulta, desearia poder poblar una tabla desde un archivo, la particularidad es que es un Excel y no un archivo plano (txt).

Comment: Con BCP o BULK INSERT no vas a poder por que no "entienden" una archivo Excel, solo podrías si de forma intermedia conviertes el excel a un archivo de texto separado por tabs o comas. Si esa podría ser una solución ya tienes una respuesta que va por ese camino.

Answer (score 0):

tuve q hacer algo parecido hace unos días.
Primero convertí el xls en txt.
Segundo cree la tabla con los campos acordes a los datos q le vas a pasar.
Y luego lo hice con Bulk, con Sql Server 2012.

```
BULK
INSERT mitabla
FROM 'c:\temp\listado.txt'--Ruta archivo

WITH

( FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', --separa campos
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\r' ) --separa filas
GO
```

Así me paso todos los registros. Eran mas de 100000
Suerte

Comment: Muchas Gracias por las Rtas. Voy a probar de pasar a formato XLSX a CVS, que tampoco es nada simple desde un BAT, ya que todo esto debe ser automático. Pero ya me ayudaron en la mitad del problema. Muchas Gracias a todos.